# Is there any way to call send method on composed mail opened in inline reply based on custom button click event

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

We have added a button using add-in express on Outlook's inline reply compose window. We want to call send event (after some processing) on this button click event(button is must as it gives choice to user to process the mail during send or else user can use normal send button for unprocessed mail) on mailitem obtained using ActiveInlineResponse. But as per MSDN we can not call send button on MailIten of the inline response object. is there any workaround we can use to obtain this MailItem on which send event can be called? any pointers will help.

Thanks,
Omkar

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61142613/using-activeinlineresponse-in-vsto-add-in-send-mailitem-after-modifying-header/61144021#comment108226887_61144021

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, with the help of above link, now I am able to send the inline response.