# Is there any way to call send method on email opened in inline reply based on custom send button click

Tags: outlook, office365, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have found a similar post by another user.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61183940/is-there-any-way-to-call-send-method-on-composed-mail-opened-in-inline-reply-bas](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

which is answered, But the page which has answer is no longer active
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61142613/using-activeinlineresponse-in-vsto-add-in-send-mailitem-after-modifying-header/61144021#comment108226887_61144021](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Tried noting as such 
Edit :   I did call the Item.Send in the Inspector Activate event.. and new inspector event where i call the activate method.
But the window does not disappear unless I click on the window icon in the task bar [to bring it to focus.].

```
void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {
        Base objBase = new Base();
        dynamic mailItem = objBase.GetItemObject(Inspector.CurrentItem);

        var inspector = Inspector as Outlook.InspectorEvents_10_Event;
        if (inspector != null)
        {
            inspector.Close += Inspectors_CloseInspector;
        }
        if (mailItem != null)
        {
            //if (mailItem.EntryID == null)
            //{
            if (mailItem is Outlook.MailItem)
            {
                if (IsInlineItem)
                {

                    _MailItem = mailItem;
                    ((Outlook.InspectorEvents_Event)Inspector).Activate += new Outlook.InspectorEvents_ActivateEventHandler(InspectorActivate);
                    ((Outlook.InspectorEvents_Event)Inspector).Deactivate += new Outlook.InspectorEvents_DeactivateEventHandler(InspectorDeactivate);
                    ((Outlook.InspectorEvents_Event)Inspector).Close += new Outlook.InspectorEvents_CloseEventHandler(Inspectors_CloseInspector);
                    Inspector.Activate();

                }
                else if (mailItem.Sent == false)
                { _MailItem = mailItem; }
                else
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem);
                }


            }
            else
            {
                _MailItem = mailItem;
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem);
            }
            //}

        }

       
        objBase.WriteError("new Inspector");
    }






 private void InspectorActivate()
        {
            Base objBase = new Base();
            Outlook.Inspector ActiveInspector = Application.ActiveInspector();
            if (ActiveInspector is null)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                //Base objBase = new Base();
                dynamic selectedItem = objBase.GetItemObject(ActiveInspector.CurrentItem);
                if (selectedItem != null && _MailItem.Subject == selectedItem.Subject && selectedItem.Sent == false)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        selectedItem.Send();
                       
                       
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(selectedItem);
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ActiveInspector);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That question got deleted. I will repost the answer:

Yes, OOM blocks some methods for the inline response. The best you can do is simulate a click on the Send button using the accessibility API.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it exposes `SafeExplorer.ActiveInlineResponseSend` method:

```
SafeExplorer sExplorer = new Redemption.SafeExplorer();
sExplorer.Item = Application.ActiveExplorer;
sExplorer.ActiveInlineResponseSend();
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Explorer.ActiveInlineResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.activeinlineresponse) property returns an item object representing the active inline response item in the explorer reading pane. You ca use the same properties and methods of the `MailItem` object on this item, except for the following:

- `MailItem.Actions` property
- `MailItem.Close` method
- `MailItem.Copy` method
- `MailItem.Delete` method
- `MailItem.Forward` method
- `MailItem.Move` method
- `MailItem.Reply` method
- `MailItem.ReplyAll` method
- `MailItem.Send` method

As you can see the Send method is not supported on the inline response items in Outlook.

As a possible workaround you may call the `Display` method which can open the item in a new inspector window where you could get the instance and call the `Send` method. The [NewInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspectors.newinspector) event is fired whenever a new inspector window is opened, either as a result of user action or through program code. But I'd suggest getting the [Inspector.Activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.activate(even)) event fired to get the `MailItem` instance and call the `Send` method.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for your reply ! 
I tried calling the MailItem.Send() in the new Inspector Event after Calling the Display Method,  
But i still get the same error.. 
I will try the Inspector.Activate and confirm if that is working.. 
Thanks again

Comment: Well Inspector.Activate did resolve the issue, But can you guide me on how can we hide the Active Inspector of the Inline Response popout window which shows on MailITem.Display() Method. The reply window appears and does not disappear until i click on task bar to select the window [to focus on window] ..... I hope i am making sense.. I will mark this as answer as soon as i am able to resolve this issue.. Thanks again

Comment: The window is closed when you call the `Send` method of the item displayed in the Inspector window. So, if you do that immediately  the user will not see the window or it may blink shortly.

Comment: Happy New Year !!
I did try to call the send as mentioned in the question edit .. but the window does not disappear .. I am using Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2211 Build 16.0.15831.20098) 64-bit... Does the version have to do anything with this issue,.. 
Thanks again

Comment: Following is the chronology of the events called as i call display method of the inline email from a custom form...   Display called>>> New Inspector>>  Activate>>  DeActivate.. After the New Inspector call the window shows up and does not go untill i click on task bar and click on the new window. Thats when the Activate method is called  item send activates...i have tried multiple solutions but it is not working ...